# Unable to receive emails to root@example.com

Tags: email

I recently discovered that the following services won't accept `root@example.com` as a valid email address.

- LinkedIn - It'll accept it, but the verification email will never get delivered.
- Facebook - It won't accept the email address in the first place.

I'd like to know the reason for this being forbidden, a Google search didn't turn any documentation as to this issue.

---

Please note that alternate addresses, like `hello@example.com` works fine, it's just `root` that these services have trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally `root@example.com` would literally be the mailbox of the root account on a Unix/Unix-like server, so while there probably isn't any reason why it's invalid, and indeed, there's no reason why it shouldn't be a virtual address on a mail system, it is plausible that a service that uses email may not regard it as a legitimate address for individual or private communication.